# Очищать корзину в сессии после ухода с шагов заказа?

Tags: веб-программирование, интернет-магазин

есть проблема, заказчики захотели обнулять шаги заказа при ухода пользователя со страниц шагов заказа, была сделана реализация, принцип:

- js слушает событие 'unload' и ставит куку
- кука не ставится, если юзер нажимает следующие шаги, ну или любую 
  навигацию внутри шагов (тупо хардкод по элементам с завязкой на 'click' и очищением слушателя 'unload')
- сервер смотрит куку, ну и очищает шаги собственно говоря

Эта схема нереально глючит, так как я могу просто обновить страницу внутри шагов, а еще недавно внедрили новый функционал и теперь на одном из шагов есть форма, ну и при посте страница перезагружается, ну вы поняли..

Гуглил, не смог найти как у других сделано.

Какие еще существуют механизмы такого функционала?